# Pivot Dataframe with String values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, spreadsheet

Let's say we have a simple dataframe that we want to pivot, like:

```
d = {"Equipment": ["Gym", "Gym", "Class", "Class", "Office", "Office"],
"Details": ["Barbell", "Ball", "Desk", "Desk", "Chair", "Lamp"],
"Recipient": ["Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Clara", "Clara", "John"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

[image]

I want to pivot to get a df to save to spreadsheet such that the result is like the following:

[image]

Naively using pivot like: `df.pivot(index="Recipient", columns=["Equipment", "Details"])` doesn't work, although I expected it would do something similar:

[image]

Pointers or examples are much appreciated!

Comment: You seem to look for [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html): `pd.crosstab(df.Recipient, [df.Equipment, df.Details])`?

Comment: @Neither Thanks! I was not aware of this functioanlity! Let me see if I can get it done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Neither](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17693816/neither) mentioned, the answer is given by the pandas.crosstab function.

The command

```
df = pd.crosstab(index=df["Recipient"], columns=[df["Equipment"],df["Details"]])
```

outputs:

[image]